# PHP Exec creates hundreds of processes

Tags: php, shell, centos

I am trying to solve a strange issue. Whenever I run a command from php script it creates hundreds of processes and server goes down in few minutes.

Here is what I am doing:

### test.php

```
exec('/usr/bin/php -q /path/to/my/script.php title=Hello', $output);
var_dump($output);
```

### script.php

```
die('Request received');
```

That's it really. If I run test.php from command line it works fine but as soon as I run from browser I get this strange issue.

What am I doing wrong here?

### Edit

It's worth to mention I am running PHP 5.3. I am only running above code, no less no more. I have tested it on two different centos machines and got same issue.

Comment: It works for me. It outputs `array(1) { [0]=> string(16) "Request received" }` in my browser. Is that the whole code in test.php?

Comment: @MarianoD'Ascanio yes that's the whole script. I have checked this in two servers and I got same issue.

Comment: does your php have the good executions rights on the script.php ?

Comment: @Bob0t Yes, it does have.

Comment: Mhhh maybe [THIS LINK](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php#refsect1-function.exec-notes) can help you ...

Comment: _What am I doing wrong here?_ Using exec().

Comment: @AlexHowansky How is it wrong?

Comment: Generally, you want to avoid exec() whenever possible. If you have code that relies on it, you can make it better/faster/safer by not relying on it. In this particular case, your web server is spawning a CLI PHP to run a script that it could simply run itself. I.e., why does the test.php launcher/wrapper even exist? Just run the target script directly.

Comment: @AlexHowansky it's a scheduled cron job. I am just stuck with creating multiple processes so I decided to write a simple script to see whether issue is in my code or somewhere else. I hope it makes sense now?

Comment: So just have cron launch script.php directly. The test.php wrapper is still unneeded.